# Right-click panel doesn't show on applications that didn't come with elementary loki

Tags: wine

When I right click the top bar of an application nothing happens, when i try that with an application that is marked as always on top (through wine) it sometimes switches between always on top and not(doesn't work always).

I downloaded elementary again and tested it on liveCD and it had the same bug.